# How to use linq where clause to fill listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a simple project which i want to search bar to fill a listview base on user input. But this is the error code that shows:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS7036:
>   There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Chiefdom'

In my sqlitehelper this what my task query.

```cs
public Task<CommodityList> GetSearchComoditylistAsync(string Chiefdom)
{
    return db.Table<CommodityList>().Where(i => i.Chiefdom == Chiefdom).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

In my cs page this what I have:

```cs
async void SearchBar_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comoList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetSearchComoditylistAsync();
    if (comoList != null)
    {
        lvChiefCommodity.ItemsSource = comoList;
    }
}
```

All what I want is when ever a user input or enter something into the search bar and hit enter key it should fill the listview according to the input.

Comment: you need to specify the table - db.Table<TableName>().Where

Comment: he table is there but still not working.

public Task<CommodityList> GetSearchComoditylistAsync(string Chiefdom)
        {
            return db.Table<CommodityList>().Where(i => i.Chiefdom == Chiefdom).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

Comment: does it fail with the same error?  Does your CommodityList class contain a string property named "Chiefdom"?

Comment: Yes as you can see

using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SLCommoditys.Models
{
   public class CommodityList
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Items { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string Chiefdom { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetSearchComoditylistAsync` has one required parameter, `Chiefdom`

```
public Task<CommodityList> GetSearchComoditylistAsync(string Chiefdom)
{
    return db.Table<CommodityList>().Where(i => i.Chiefdom == Chiefdom).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

but when you call it you are not passing any parameters

```
async void SearchBar_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comoList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetSearchComoditylistAsync();
```

you presumably want to pass in the search string

```
var search = (SearchBar)sender;
var comoList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetSearchComoditylistAsync(search.Text);
```

your current search function only returns ONE result.  If you want to return more than that,

```
return db.Table<CommodityList>().Where(i => i.Chiefdom.ToUpper().Contains(Chiefdom.ToUpper()).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Still saying : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Chiefdom'

Comment: Thanks a lot. We getting there. But small thing to be done to finish it up. How to can i get the search itmes into listview. Like :    lvChiefCommodity.ItemsSource = comoList;

Comment: Sorry I went out:  Please check this :     async void SearchBar_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var search = (SearchBar)sender;
            var comoList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetSearchComoditylistAsync(search.Text);

            lvChiefCommodity.ItemsSource = comoList;
    
        }

Comment: And this is the error code   :         Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'SLCommoditys.Models.CommodityList' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: you search query returns ONE item - a ListView requires a collection of items

Comment: Any help or guidelines please?

Comment: this is a design problem, and I can't design your app for you.  Is your search supposed to return more than one result?  Most search functions do.  If so, you need to modify your search logic to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help and God bless.

Comment: Thank you very my brother. Your advice really helped me. I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

public Task> GetItemsNotDoneAsync(string Chiefdom)
        {
            return db.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM CommodityList WHERE Chiefdom=?",Chiefdom);
        }

Comment: On my cs.page
async void SearchBar_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entry_Search.Text))
            {
                //Get Commodity  
                var comodity = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsNotDoneAsync((Entry_Search.Text));
                if (comodity != null)
                {
                    lvCommodity.ItemsSource = comodity;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "There is no item in this Chiefdom", "OK");
            }